# Download Master File using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, master-page, download

How do I download a masterpage file using PowerShell?

e.g. URL: `http://sharepoint/_catalogs/masterpage/file.master`

Answer (score 2):

To list all master pages:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;

Get-SPWebApplication | Get-SPSite -Limit All | Get-SPWeb -Limit All | Select Title, URL, MasterUrl
```

To download a specific file / master page:

```
$fromsite = "<your sp url>"

$fromfile = "/_catalogs/masterpage/seattle.master"
$tofile   = "c:\seattle.master"

$web = Get-SPWeb $fromsite
$file = $web.GetFile($fromfile)
$filebytes = $file.OpenBinary()

$filestream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($tofile, "Create")
$binarywriter = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter($filestream)
$binarywriter.write($filebytes)
$binarywriter.Close()
```